# how capture the image which is similar to alt plus print screen?

Tags: java, swing

Am trying the capture image quality and size similar to ALT + printscreen. Could anyone please help me out for the same?

I tried the following code to capture:

```
dimScreenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
rectScreenSize = new Rectangle (dimScreenSize);
BufferedImage bufimg=robot.createScreenCapture (rectScreenSize);
```

After captured the image I used to store it in particular location, and again i fetch the image and resized it using `thumbnails`.

```
loc =d_path+"\\a"+m+"a"+".jpg"; 
Thumbnails.of(new File(loc)).size(800, 800).outputQuality(1f).toFile(new File(loc));
```

But the image quality too bad. Please help me out, Is there is any otherway?

Answer (score 1):

If the image quality isn't satisfactory you could try another format such as png?

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Capture
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write(screenShot, "png", new File("screenShot.png"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class AltPrintScreen {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedFlavorException, AWTException {

            Robot robot = new Robot();

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );
            }

            Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
            RenderedImage image = (RenderedImage)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);

            boolean isSuccess = ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("altScreen.png"));

            System.out.println(isSuccess);
        }
    }
```